# Twisted - sending data to selected clients

Tags: python, networking, twisted

There is this server I made with Twisted which receives strings from a client and send it to all of the other connected clients.
But is there a way to send the string to just clients that the sender wanted to send it to ? If so, how do I do it in code ? This is what I did so far (NOTE I am a complete noob in Python. I just need to build a server for my iOS app, so I am sorry if the question is silly):

```
from twisted.internet.protocol import Protocol, Factory
from twisted.internet import reactor


class IphoneChat(Protocol):
    def connectionMade(self):
        #self.transport.write("""connected""")
        self.factory.clients.append(self)
        print "clients are ", self.factory.clients

    def connectionLost(self, reason):
        self.factory.clients.remove(self)

    def dataReceived(self, data):
        #print "data is ", data
        a = data.split(':')
        if len(a) > 1:
            command = a[0]
            content = a[1]

            msg = ""
            if command == "iam":
                self.name = content
                msg = "iam" + self.name + " has joined"

            elif command == "msg":
                msg = self.name + ": " + content

            elif command == "img":
                msg = command + ":" + content + ":" + command

            elif command == "img2":
                msg = content

            elif command == "img3":
                msg = content

            print msg

            for c in self.factory.clients:
                c.message(msg)

    def message(self, message):
        self.transport.write(message + '\n')


factory = Factory()
factory.protocol = IphoneChat
factory.clients = []

reactor.listenTCP(53080, factory)
print "Iphone Chat server started"
reactor.run()
```

Thanks for the help

Comment: The answer is: yes. Thank you.

Comment: What ?!?! My question is way different

Comment: No, your question is exactly this: "_But is there a way to send the string to just clients that the sender wanted to send it to ?_". And the answer is exactly this: "_yes_". Please ask the question you wanted to ask, show us [what have you tried](http://whathaveyoutried.com) (preferably code snippet etc.). For now this is not really a question suitable for StackOverflow (so, as far as Stack Overflow is concerned, your "question" is not really a question).

Comment: @Tadeck Sorry, my bad. I changed the question.

Comment: can u please tell me how u solved this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
self.factory.clients[24].transport.write("You are client 24!")
```

I think should work

Comment: i am new to socket programing and python coding can u please tell where i have to change ..... i am using the same code but it is one to many .. but i need one to one communication... thanks in advance Joran  Beasley

Comment: @Joran Beasley can you please explain what you meant?